# Show an ID as a :after of a CLASS?

Tags: javascript, css

```css
#fp-nav{display:none}
.submenu:after{content:"I WANT #fp-nav HERE"}
```

```html
<div class="submenu"> </div>
<div id="fp-nav">01 / 52</div>
```

Let's say I have an ID counter that updates every section change: 01 / XX, 02 / xx and so on...

How can I keep that ID hidden from the page and let it appear as an :after of a CLASS?

Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Maybe if you showed some code.

Comment: @epascarello I know it's difficult to explain. Have a look a the code inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got what you are trying to accomplish as epascarello says, it is unclear!

```css
body{
    counter-reset: paragraph;
}
p::before {
  counter-increment: paragraph;                
  content: "Paragraph " counter(paragraph) ": ";
}
```

```html
<p>Name</p>
<p>Last Name</p>
<p>Phone #</p>
<p>Address</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the style properties of CSS rules via the [`styleSheets` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets):

```js
// Get the rule's stylesheet and index
let ruleIndex = -1;
let sheet = null;
let sheetRules = null;
Array.from(document.styleSheets).some(s => Array.from(s.rules || s.cssRules).some((rule, index) => {
  if (rule.selectorText == ".foo::after") {
    sheet = s;
    sheetRules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules;
    ruleIndex = index;
    return true;
  }
}));

// Update it periodically
let id = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  ++id;
  sheet.deleteRule(ruleIndex);
  ruleIndex = sheet.insertRule('.foo::after { content: "' + id + '"; }', ruleIndex);
}, 250);
```

```css
.foo::after {
  content: 'foo';
}
```

```html
<span class="foo"></span>
```

You used to be able to change a rule's style properties, but they were made read-only, so now you have to remove the old rule and add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution through Jquery , you might not be able to target pseudo class like :after but you would be able to add it in the submenu div tag

```
//get value from the id
var k = $('#fp-nav').text();

// remove the element 
$('#fp-nav').remove();
//add the value inside submenu i just gave it a class value you can change it as per your need
$(".submenu").append( "<div class='idval'>"+k +"</div> ");
```